# how to localize a global string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I have a NSString as a global constant. This constant is defined by using

```
extern NSString *const kConstant;
```

in the .h file.

The value is set in the .m file (before @implementation):

```
NSString *const kConstant = @"myValue";
```

So far so good. As soon as I want to use the `NSLocalizedString` macro

```
NSString *const kConstant = NSLocalizedString(@"myValue",@"the value");
```

I get the error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant.

Any idea how to get a global string value localized?

Comment: whwere exactly did u put the line  NSString *const kConstant = NSLocalizedString(@"myValue",@"the value"); ?

Comment: Between the #import and the @implementation line within the .m file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is make the constant the key used in your localization.  You have to use `NSLocalizedString()` at the point where you need the string, because that expands into a macro/function that looks up the files in your app bundle and figures out which string to use (fallback for missing translations, etc.).  I'm afraid there's no way around it; the localization has to happen at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You should make it a class method of a class, and call `NSLocalizedString()` if it's not been allocated.  This is similar to the Singleton Pattern:

MyStatics.h:

```
@interface MyStatics : NSObject

+ (NSString *)globalString

@end
```

MyStatics.m:

```
#import "MyStatics.h"

static NSString *_globalString = nul;

@implemenetation MyStatics

+ (NSString *)globalString
{
    if (!_globalString)
        _globalString = NSLocalizedString(@"myValue",@"the value");
    return _globalString;
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I agree this would work but I had the hope, that there would be an easier solution.

Comment: @Red I don't believe there is, if you really want it to be global.  However is there any real reason you don't simply use a macro: `#define MYGLOBAL NSLocalizedString(@"myValue",@"the value")`?

Comment: @Red Are you referring to my answer or using a macro?

Comment: I meant using the macro. When I enter it in Xcode in the .h file it does not accept the NSLocalizedString.

Comment: @Red That doesn't make any sense.  This is without even trying to use the macro?

Comment: ? I'm lost, what do you mean? I thought you meant, that I should add the NSLocalizedString to the #define macro (#define MYGLOBAL NSLocalizedString(@"myValue",@"the value"). I tried this before, but - if I'm not doing something stupid- Xcode does not include it in the XLIFF file, so that I can not translate. Looks to me, as an NSLocalizedString in the .h file is not taken for the export.

Comment: @Red You need to put it into a header and import that header whereever you want to use the global.  You could probably add it to the prefix header file to have it available everywhere.

Comment: thats what I did. Xcode allows me to use it in the m files, However, when I do the Editor->Export for Localization and generate the XLIFF, it does not get included

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean.